# Nativescript background-image fullscreen

Tags: nativescript

I want to create app in Nativescript with fullscreen image on page. I have to use `background-image: url('~/images/background.jpg');`. But how to make it full screen.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried. Provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to use the NativeScript supported [CSS properties](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#supported-properties) to achieve this.

I've used the following CSS on a background-image attached to the `<Page>` view before and it works fine.

```
.coverImage {
    background-image: url('~/images/kiss.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need `url()` around the img path.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the `Page` to have a fullscreen image background, add your images to `/App_Resources` and do this in your component:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private page:Page) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
        this.page.backgroundImage = "res://bg-image";
    }
}
```

Update: You can add CSS to enforce fullscreen.

```css
.page {
    /* background-image: url("res://bg-image") */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* background-attachment: fixed; */ /* not supported in {N} yet */
    background-position: center top; /* instead set ypos to top to avoid scroll-up */
}
```

*Note: Assign this CSS class to your `Page`.*

Comment: This doesn't scale it to fullscreen though unfortunatley.

Comment: It does work with CSS but unfortunately if I use any CSS the background image gets pushed up when the soft keyboard comes into view.

Comment: @BenMorris Try `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: @BenMorris seems {N} does not support `background-attachment`. So `background-position: center top` should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

if you're using nativeScipt with Angular, you can use:

```css
/*In your .css: */

.my-class {
    background-image: url("res://image-name.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!-- in your .html: -->

<ScrollView class="my-class">
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not work with animated gif.
My style:

```
.page{
    background-image: url("~/assets/images/animated.gif") black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The gif is shown, centered and enlarged, so great, but static: the animation does not moves.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
constructor(private page: Page) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.page.actionBarHidden=true;`
  this.page.backgroundImage = 'res://gold_bg';
  this.page.style.backgroundSize='cover';
  this.page.style.backgroundRepeat='no-repeat';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very large image, where the `background-size: cover;` did not show the image well neither in landscape ( squeezed and narrow ) /portrait ( goes out of the page )

Eventually what worked best for me was to add an `Image` element, and set it as background

```
<Image src="~/assets/images/background.jpg" stretch="aspectFill" left="0" top="0" width="100%" height="100%"></Image>
```

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Image src="~/assets/images/background.jpg" stretch="aspectFill" left="0" top="0" width="100%" height="100%"></Image>
    <StackLayout top="0" left="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        ... usual content here
    </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```