# NativeScript: How to set a background image?

Tags: javascript, css, nativescript

I'm trying to set a background image on my 'main-page.xml' in my NativeScript app.

I currently set the Page id to "register", as in `<Page id="register">` and tried styling it with css.

In app.css I put:

```
#register {
    background-image: url("myImage.jpeg");
}
```

The 'myImage' image is in the 'app' folder and I figured I got the url right.

Is this not how you do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a css class - what you have can work with some tweaks. This has been asked differently before and should work similarly:

`.coverImage {
    background-image: ~/images/kiss.jpg;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36501554

Answer (score 1):

- **This is if you are setting the background in css/scss file,**

```
    #register{
        background-image: url('~/images/myImage.jpeg');
        // this is to stretch the image and show without repetition.
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

**OR**

- **For inline setting of background image,**

```
    <StackLayout backgroundImage="~/images/myImage.jpeg" >
    -------
    -------
    </StackLayout>
```

This Should work!! :)