# NativeScript/NativeScript Angular - How to set a background image for the page?

Tags: css, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to create a background image but I can't seem to being able to do so.. I looked at this question:

[Nativescript background-image fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500842/nativescript-background-image-fullscreen)

But without any luck. It doesn't show enough of the markup and also the OP there doesn't seem to use `nativescript-angular` because when you use `<Page></Page>` as suggested you get an error.

And [this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1517) says that `Page` shouldn't be used with angular, and I'm positive I've read the same thing in the docs.

I use this css:

```
.login-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 40px 60px;
  background-image: ~/assets/img/login.jpg;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

With this template:

```
<StackLayout class="login-page text-center" orientation="vertical" [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <StackLayout class="input-field m-b-20">
    <TextField class="input input-rounded" formControlName="email" hint="Email"></TextField>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout class="input-field">
    <TextField class="input input-rounded" formControlName="password" hint="Password" secure="true"></TextField>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

The image is at `app/assets/img/login.jpg`. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Your code should work as expected or at least the exact same scenario is working on my side - here is the test project https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/backgroundImage

Comment: You cannot use `Page` directly, but you can programmatically. In `ngOnInit` for the component, you can `this.page.backgroundImage = "res://login"`

Answer (score 1):

At Component **Login.ts**:

```
import { Page } from "ui/page";

export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private page:Page) {
    page.backgroundImage = '~/images/login.jpg';
  }   
}
```

Must create a folder at app root named images like the Nativescript docs says.